# `ListView` content being added at bottom instead of top

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

**`ListView` content being added at bottom instead of top**

I'm using `ListView` to display a list of data elements. Previously the `height` was set to `wrap_content` and it was working fine but with few performance lags. Then I came across a blog saying `ListView`'s `height` should not be set to `wrap_content` for good performance. After doing this, i.e. setting `height` to `fill_parent`, all of my data rows started appearing at bottom of the `ListView` instead of top. Can any body point to what possibly I'm missing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post your xml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this attrubut to your list view android:stackFromBottom="false"